# Using selected values from multiple dropdowns

Tags: jquery, select

I have several drop down lists in my page to collect user preferences. I need to get the user selected value from each drop down then pass them on to a local asp program to use.
I have used :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#my_select').change(function() {

                // assign the value to a variable

                var selectVal = $('#my_select :selected').val();

                $(".test").html(selectVal);

            });
        });
```

This gets the value from one drop down but i can't seem to use this value latter in my page.
All i can find so far is how to use the value from one drop down.

Comment: u should declare the variable as global to access its data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty easy to just get all the selected values like so:

```
$('select').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("name") = $(this).val());
});
```

I've made [a Fiddle that shows this is action and builds a string of key=value pairs](http://jsfiddle.net/FtpAc/) which I believe is what the OP needs to pass to his ASP:

```
var vals = [], str=null;    
$('select').change(function(){
    getVals();
});
$('button').click(function(){
    getVals();
    printVals();
});        
function getVals(){
    vals = [];
    $('select').each(function(){
        vals[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });
};
function printVals(){
    str="";
    for (var key in vals) {
        str += ((str)?"&":"") + key + "=" + vals[key];
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This seems to be just the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var selectVal;

            $('#my_select').change(function() {

                // assign the value to a variable

                selectVal = $('#my_select option:selected').val();

                $(".test").html(selectVal);

            });
        });
```

Comment: I thought this might work.  however the   $(".test").html(selectVal); still only works inside the change function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set an ID for multiple select boxes ( #my_select) - that's incorrect to start with. If you have multiple selects, assign them either a unique ID each or (better) a style (like .my_select). Then you can modify your js as follows:

```
        $('.my_select').change(function() {

            // assign the value to a variable

            var selectVal = $("option:selected", this);

            $(".test").html(selectVal);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
$('#my_select').change(function () {

    $(".test").html("");
    $('#my_select :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        // assign the value to a variable
        var selectVal = $(this).val();
        $(".test").append(selectVal);
    });

});
```

Comment: No need for :selected. you can test its val

Answer (score 0):

```
 var g = {};
 $('select').change(function ()
 {
     var all = $('select').map(function (i, n)
     {
         return {
             'name': this.name,
             'val': this.value
         }
     }).get();
     var goingToServer = JSON.stringify(all); //do what ever...
     console.log(goingToServer);
 });
```

this is the reponse for you to send to server :

`[{"name":"s1","val":"v1"},{"name":"s2","val":"v4"},{"name":"s3","val":"v6"}]`

[**example**](http://jsbin.com/aKEzEJa/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

*To achieve the best performance when using :selected to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":selected").*

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var selectVal;  //Globalize the variable

      $('#my_select').change(function() { 

      selectVal = $('#my_select option').filter(":selected").val();

      $(".test").html(selectVal);

       });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

**html code:**

```
<select class="select_field" id="l_type" name="l_type">
    <option value=" ">Select type</option>
    <option value="cu">Cu</option>
    <option value="Ve">Ve</option>
    <option value="Ex">Ex</option>
</select>
<select class="select_field" id="l_type" name="l_type">
    <option value=" ">Select type</option>
    <option value="cu">Cu</option>
    <option value="Ve">Ve</option>
    <option value="Ex">Ex</option>
</select>
<select class="select_field" id="l_type" name="l_type">
    <option value=" ">Select type</option>
    <option value="cu">Cu</option>
    <option value="Ve">Ve</option>
    <option value="Ex">Ex</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="GetVal"/>
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectVal = [];
    $('input:button').click(function () {
        $('select').each(function(i,e){            
            selectVal.push($('select:eq('+i+') option:selected').val());            
        });
        console.log(selectVal);
    });
});
```

and finally **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/eSzrg/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/5NPLB/)** for you. Check it out

HTML :

```
<select name="select_box_1" id="select_box_1" class="sel_boxes">
<option value="select_box_1_value_1">select_box_1_value_1</option>
<option value="select_box_1_value_2">select_box_1_value_2</option>
</select>

<select name="select_box_2" id="select_box_2" class="sel_boxes">
<option value="select_box_2_value_1">select_box_2_value_1</option>
<option value="select_box_2_value_2">select_box_2_value_2</option>
</select>

<select name="select_box_3" id="select_box_3" class="sel_boxes">
<option value="select_box_3_value_1">select_box_3_value_1</option>
<option value="select_box_3_value_2">select_box_3_value_2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.sel_boxes').change(function(){
    var param_string="";
    $('.sel_boxes').each(function(index) {
        var elem_name = $(this).attr('name');
        var elem_value = $(this).val();

        param_string = param_string+elem_name+"="+elem_value+"&";
    });
    param_string = param_string.substring(0, param_string.length - 1)
    alert(param_string)
});
```